# Yii2 Object of class ..... could not be converted to string

Tags: php, database, yii2-advanced-app

i want to show one data from table client when create data Goods, but i got error Object of class frontend\modules\cargo\models\Client could not be converted.

here is GoodsController

```
public function actionCreate()
{
  $model = new Goods();
  $idClient = Yii::$app->user->identity->id_client;
  $client = Client::find($idClient)->one();

  if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  } else {
      return $this->render('create', [
          'model' => $model,
          'client' => $client,
      ]);
  }
}
```

I need to display data client in _form Goods.somebody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get object of Client with that specific id you can do it in two ways.

```
Client::find($idClient);
```

or with `->one()`:

```
Client::find()->where(['id' => $idClient])->one();
```

Comment: thank you it's work. but i don't know why only two field is displayed from three.

Answer (score 0):

filters and ... should not be added as a argument to find.

**findOne**

```
Client::findOne($idClient);
Client::findOne(['id' => $idClient])
```

**find**

```
Client::find()->where(['id' => $idClient])->one();
Client::find()->where('id = :id', [':id' => $idClient])->one();
```